# Meaning of the word "illuded"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

I'm doing some test online (on Upwork) and this is one question:

> Complete the following sentence:
>
> The herd of gazelles successfully __________ the wild cheetahs.
>
> 1. alluded
> 2. eluded
> 3. *illuded*

So, I think the first and the second couldn't be right for this sentence, so remains the third, but I don't know is there some mistake with this, can't find translate. What that means? Should some similar word be written instead of that?

Answer (score 6):

- "allude" means to *suggest* or *imply*.
- "elude" means to *escape from*, or *avoid*.
- "illude" means to *trick* or *delude* [rare]

All your options are just the past tense of these.

So you have your meaning of "illuded", and I would say the correct answer is:

> The herd of gazelles successfully **eluded** the wild cheetahs.

Because gazelles would normally outrun or *avoid* predators to *escape* from them. I suppose it could be argued that on occasions an animal could *trick* a predator, but the word *illude* is cited by dictionaries as *rare*, and could possibly even be considered *archaic*. I am certain that the word you are looking for is *eluded*.

Comment: My paper dictionary (SOED) says that 'illude' is 'now rare' (now being about 60 years ago) and cites a use of the word in 1420. Take my advice: just don't use that word if you wish to communicate with anyone.

Comment: @JeremyC Good point, I have added reference to this.